# Using anonymus IEnumerable type

Tags: c#

This may be a simple question but I can not figure this out...

If I have this code,

```
IEnumerable myVar = (from i in MyList
          select new 
          {
               NewText= i.Text,
               NewValue = i.Value
          });
```

How can I user the values in myVar (without changing the type(`IEnumerable`))?

like

```
foreach (var i in myVar)
{
    //i....
}
```

---

EDIT :

My actual code returns `IEnumerable`

```
public IEnumerable GetData(IEnumerable<int> priceDetailId)
{
   ....

   return (from i in MyList
              select new 
              {
                   NewText= i.Text,
                   NewValue = i.Value
              });
}
```

Then I need to use the result in  a loop..

```
var result  = GetData();
foreach (var i in result)
{
    //i....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, because the enumerator of `IEnumerable` returns instances of type `object`. You would first need to cast those to the actual type. Since the type is anonymous, you can't do that.

Change the type of `myVar` to `var` to make it work:

```
var myVar = from i in MyList
            select new 
            {
                NewText= i.Text,
                NewValue = i.Value
            };
```

However, the `return` in your - currently illegal - code, indicates that the LINQ query actually is inside another method that returns the result and that's the reason why you want to keep `IEnumerable`.
In that case, using an anonymous type is not the correct approach, because it leads to the exact problem you are having.
You should create a simple class and use that in your query and change your return type to `IEnumerable<YourClass>`

Finally, if you insist on using an anonymous type and `IEnumerable`, you can make use of the `dynamic` keyword inside your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(dynamic i in myVar)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.NewValue);
}
```

However, you no longer will have compile time safety, so if you have a typo when accessing the dynamic variable you will get a runtime exception instead of a compiler error.
Example: `Console.WriteLine(i.Foo);` would compile although there is no `Foo` property in the anonymous type. Upon execution however, it would throw a `RuntimeBinderException`.

Comment: Your guess is correct it is a method returning a `IEnumerable`, Added the actual code as an Edit and deleted the 'return' in the original code... :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

```
var myVar = from i in MyList
            select new 
            {
                Text= i.Text,
                Value = i.Value
            });

foreach(var x in myVar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Text={0} Value={1}", x.Text, x.Value);
}
```

The non-generic `IEnumerable` is not strongly typed in the `foreach`.

But since yout want to return the anonymous type from a method, that doesn't work. Return an `IEnumerable<CustomClass>` instead, e.g.:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(string text, string value) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Value{ get; set; }
}
```

Now you can create an `IEnumerable<Item>` and return that instead:

```
IEnumerable<Item> allItems = MyList.Select(i => new Item(i.Text, i.Value))
                                   .ToList();
return allItems;
```

Comment: What if I want to return the result out from a function, Then I guess I can not use `var` as return type...

Comment: No, but you can neither return an anonymous type.

Comment: @Nalaka526: My answer addresses this problem.